# Issues with data types in pandas functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to design a function in python pandas that inputs the lon/lat of the origin and the lon/lat of the destination and outputs the haversine’s distance between the two coordinates (in miles), and then append this distance in a column next to my original values in the dataframe. My original dataset in pandas has a comlumn for lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, with 5-6 coordinates below. I used the code below, and everything seemed to be running swimmingly (the code worked at first), until I got an error message TypeError: input must be an array, list, tuple or scalar. It appears that this issue is occurring because the numbers I am feeding into my function are in pd.series format, and I have tried using the np.array function to convert them into an array. The error still come up though.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to fix this issue?

Thanks so much,
MG

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

def haversine_np(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)

    All args must be of equal length.    

    """
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(np.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = np.sin(dlat/2.0)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2.0)**2

    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))
    r = 3956 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    return c * r

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#reads from csv created externally

df2 = pd.read_csv('\Users\grossmanmb\Desktop\PythonGPS\locations.csv')
print(df2)

# creates dataframe with haversine formula from origin to destination

'''
# calculates distance between location in lat1/lon1 and lat2/lon2 for  every row in dataframe
# this dataframe is setup so that the origin in every case is "home"
# IOW, the distance that is caluclated depends on what lat1/lon1 and   lat2/lon2 are for each row
'''

df3 = { 'distance(m)' : (haversine_np(df2['longitude1'],df2['latitude1'],df2['longitude2'],df2['latitude2']))}
print(df3)

# appends haversine dostance column to original dataframe

df2['distance(m)']= df3['distance(m)']
print(df2)
```

Sample data:

```
df6 = pd.DataFrame({'origin':['home','home','home'], 'destination':['Bethesda','Rockville', 'Washington'], 'latitude1' :[37.99, 37.99, 37.99], 'longitude1' :[-77.17, -77.17, -77.17], 'latitude2' :[38.98, 39.08, 38.89], 'longitude2' :[-77.09, -77.15, -77.02]})

In [56]: df6
Out[56]:
  destination  latitude1  latitude2  longitude1  longitude2 origin
0    Bethesda      37.99      38.98      -77.17      -77.09   home
1   Rockville      37.99      39.08      -77.17      -77.15   home
2  Washington      37.99      38.89      -77.17      -77.02   home
```

Comment: can you post a small (3-5 rows) but reproducible (that would help to reproduce your error) data set?

Comment: Yest thanks so much. Here's a small sample pd.dataframe I was working with. The goal is to get the code to iterate through all the "origins" and "destinations" and calculate haversine's for each.

df6 = pd.DataFrame({'origin':['home','home','home'],
                   'destination':['Bethesda','Rockville', 'Washington'],
                   'latitude1' :[37.99, 37.99, 37.99],
                   'longitude1' :[-77.17, -77.17, -77.17],
                   'latitude2' :[38.98, 39.08, 38.89],
                   'longitude2' :[-77.09, -77.15, -77.02]})

Comment: i can't reproduce your error... Which line of code produces this error?

Comment: Sorry this is getting more confusing. It doesn't produce an error the first time I run it either. What I'm realizing is that it only produces an error after I run a second piece of code that maps this data. This extra code turns the pandas df data into lists in order to plot them on a map (e.g. homelat = df2['latitude1'].tolist() ). I think this may mess up my attached code be changing the format of the original data. I may be able to solve the problem by creating an extra variable with these data, in order to keep the original data in tact.